# two children has same implementation of F() , other two children has different implementation of F, all four derive from same class

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have the following class hierarchy.

```
class Base
{
 virtual void F();
}

class Derived1 : public Base
{
  void F() {
        cout<< " one implementation"<<endl;
  }
}
class Derived2 : public Base
{
  void F() {
        cout<< " one implementation"<<endl;
  }
}
class Derived3 : public Base
{
  void F() {
        cout<< " other implementation"<<endl;
  }
}
class Derived4 : public Base
{
  void F() {
        cout<< " other implementation"<<endl;
  }
}
```

Introducing more classes in the hierarchy like following seems to solve the issue

```
class Base
    {
     virtual void F();
    }

class Base1 : public Base {
    void F() {
            cout<< " one implementation"<<endl;
      }
}

class Base2 : public Base {
    void F() {
            cout<< " other implementation"<<endl;
      }
}

    class Derived1 : public Base1
    {

    }
    class Derived2 : public Base1
    {

    }
    class Derived3 : public Base2
    {

    }
    class Derived4 : public Base2
    {

    }
```

I was wondering if the above use case of few siblings having same implementation than other siblings can be tackled better? Is there any obvious design pattern which i am missing here?

If F is the only functionality i want may be I can solve it just by composition( see below). I do not know whether it is a good idea to do that.

***composition***

```
class Base
    {
     virtual void F();
    }

class Base1 : public Base {
    void F() {
            cout<< " one implementation"<<endl;
      }
}

class Base2 : public Base {
    void F() {
            cout<< " other implementation"<<endl;
      }
}

    class Derived1 
    {
      Base * Fer;
      Derived1()
      {
        Fer = new Base1();
      }
    }
    class Derived2
    {
      Base * Fer;
      Derived1()
      {
        Fer = new Base1();
      }
    }
    class Derived3 
    {
      Base * Fer;
      Derived1()
      {
        Fer = new Base2();
      }
    }
    class Derived4
    {
      Base * Fer;
      Derived1()
      {
        Fer = new Base2();
      }
    }
```

Comment: May be what you described is oversimplified. The _Decorator Pattern_ comes to mind for me.

Comment: Well, not really, I am facing the exact problem and now I am thinking of redesigning and making it future proof. I will look into decorator pattern thanks.

Comment: Yes, this could be achieved by using decorators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use composition, but this way:

```
#include <iostream>

// define an interface
class Base
{
 virtual void F() = 0;
};

// define an implementation framework which pulls in templated
// components to do the work
template<class HandleF>
struct Impl : Base
{
    virtual void F() override {
        f_handler(this);
    }

    HandleF f_handler;
};

struct OneImplementationOfF
{
    template<class Self>
    void operator()(Self* self) const
    {
        std::cout<< " one implementation"<< std::endl;
    }
};

struct OtherImplementationOfF
{
    template<class Self>
    void operator()(Self* self) const
    {
        std::cout<< " other implementation"<< std::endl;
    }
};

// now build our classes    
class Derived1 : public Impl<OneImplementationOfF>
{
};

class Derived2 : public Impl<OneImplementationOfF>
{
};

class Derived3 : public Impl<OtherImplementationOfF>
{
};

class Derived4 : public Impl<OtherImplementationOfF>
{
};
```